# Azure Data Factory: ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value : ErrorCode: 2200

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can somoene let me know why Azure Data Factory is trying to convert a value from String to type Double.

I am getting the error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '+44 07878 44444' for column name 'telephone2' from type 'String' (precision:255, scale:255) to type 'Double' (precision:15, scale:255). Additional info: Input string was not in a correct format.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Table to EnrDB",
    "details": [
        {
            "errorCode": 0,
            "message": "'Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'",
            "details": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My Sink looks like the following:

[image]

I don't have any mapping set

[image]

The column setting for the the field 'telephone2' is as follows:

[image]

I changed the 'table option' to none, however I got the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Internal system error occurred.\r\nStatement ID: {C2C38377-5A14-4BB7-9298-28C3C351A40E} | Query hash: 0x2C885D2041993FFA | Distributed request ID: {6556701C-BA76-4D0F-8976-52695BBFE6A7}. Total size of data scanned is 134 megabytes, total size of data moved is 102 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Internal system error occurred.\r\nStatement ID: {C2C38377-5A14-4BB7-9298-28C3C351A40E} | Query hash: 0x2C885D2041993FFA | Distributed request ID: {6556701C-BA76-4D0F-8976-52695BBFE6A7}. Total size of data scanned is 134 megabytes, total size of data moved is 102 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=75000,Class=17,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=17,Number=75000,State=1,Message=Internal system error occurred.,},{Class=0,Number=15885,State=1,Message=Statement ID: {C2C38377-5A14-4BB7-9298-28C3C351A40E} | Query hash: 0x2C885D2041993FFA | Distributed request ID: {6556701C-BA76-4D0F-8976-52695BBFE6A7}. Total size of data scanned is 134 megabytes, total size of data moved is 102 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Table to EnrDB",
    "details": []
}
```

Any more thoughts

Comment: You already have the table and you are trying to upsert to that table based on key column `id`. If this is the case, I see that you have selected `auto create table option` in the sink settings. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @SaideepArikontham, that is correct. Should I remove 'auto create table option'

Comment: Yes. Remove it and check again. Since you are passing the table name to the dataset (table already exists), remove the option and check once.

Comment: I will remove it now, and see if that resolves the issue thank you.

Comment: Also try to import schema and check if the mapping is correct or not after removing auto create table option.'

Comment: I don't think I can use that option because that copy activity imports over 70 tables... not just a single table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250218/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).

Comment: Hi @SaideepArikontham, I have updated the question. I changed the table option to none as you suggested, but I got the error in the update

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by changing the column DataType on the database to match the DataType recorded in Azure Data Factory i.e StringType